# "Неверно задано имя папки" при запуске батника для регистрации DLL

Tags: c#, bat

Задача запустить батник для регистрации DLL, на компе под админом все работает.
Но если запустить на другом компе под пользователем пишет
"Неверно задано имя папки"

Создана учетка специально для этих нужд с правами админа

```
Process pr = new Process();
                pr.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                pr.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\" + userName + @"\Documents\DLL2.bat";
                pr.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
                pr.StartInfo.UserName = "admin";
                pr.StartInfo.Domain = "os";
                pr.StartInfo.Password = "password";
                pr.Start();
```

Пробовал запустить и так "C:\DLL2.bat" - ошибка та же.

Comment: "Неверно задано имя папки". Путь к папке проверяли, он существует именно такой? Пробелов в пути нет? Из несистемных папок работает?

Comment: пробовал  запустить и так "C:\DLL2.bat"; ошибка таже

Comment: Добавил в вопрос. Часть с паролем убрал - она для вопроса лишняя.

Comment: Если запускать батник не влоб, а через `cmd /c "C:\Users\userName\Documents\DLL2.bat"` - та же фигня? И что именно написано в батнике? может, какая-то из строк батника приводит к указанной ошибке?

Comment: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\1cv8\8.3.10.2699\bin\comcntr.dll" /u
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\1cv8\8.3.12.1685\bin\comcntr.dll"
Это написано в батнике

Comment: попробовал через cmd, тоже самое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил строчку и проблема исчезла

pr.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe");

Comment: На разных машинах пути к системной папке могут различаться. Используйте [Environment.SystemDirectory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.systemdirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2) или [Environment.GetFolderPath](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=netframework-4.7.2) + [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.7.2).